# SVN: analog of hg's addremove

Tags: svn, version-control, mercurial

We have a repository with several files (no folders). Each build time we have to download the same folder from another source (db), then commit to SVN changes - update existing, remove not existed and add new files.

So idea is to have 'copy' of db's scripts in SVN each build (that's why **MSBuild** is used)

Problem is that I don't know analog of **hg**'s *addremove* - which automatically synchronize two folders.

does anyone know how *addremove* can be simulated?

Comment: Here's a post that includes two shell aliases (one called add_all and another called rm_all).  This would basically make it possible for you to run 'add_all && rm_all' to do exactly what 'hg addremove' does, but with subversion.  http://www.plexusweb.com/staff/travis/blog/post/267/Batch-addremove-files-to-Subversion

Comment: I can't believe this isn't possible with svn, but I can't see how. If there are no better option, you might want to consider using hgsubversion to maintain a local hg repo, use `hg addremove` on that and then push the changes back to svn.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I personally have a little bash script to do that (being on linux):

```
svn status | grep "^\?" | gawk '{print $2}' | xargs -r svn add
svn status | grep "^\!" | gawk '{print $2}' | xargs -r svn remove
```

EDIT: Thanks to [cesar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/152993/cesar), here's a simpler version:

```
svn status | gawk '/^\?.*/ {print $2}' | xargs -r svn add
svn status | gawk '/^\!.*/ {print $2}' | xargs -r svn remove
```

Comment: why not skip grep and just go with:

`svn status | gawk '/^\?.*/ {print $2}' | xargs -r svn add`

Comment: @anonymous Good question, probably because I already had piped through grep to see the actual output before trying to do something with it. And of course not actually reading the gawk man page and therefore not knowing about that syntax. Thanks.

Comment: What about filenames containing spaces? I don't know enough gawk syntax to change the record seperator to \0...

Answer (score 1):

For this sort of thing, I just use mercurial, and check in and out of svn with:
https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/HgSubversion
... might not be exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I've always used the `svn_load_dirs.pl` script that comes with svn for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

(Improvement of @Eric-Karl's answer)

Works for:

- paths with 'space' chars
- paths with '@' chars
- paths with '\' chars (in MSYS shell)

---

```
svn status | perl -ne 'print "$1\0" if /^\?\s+([^\r\n]+)/' | xargs -0 -r -I FILE svn add 'FILE@'
svn status | perl -ne 'print "$1\0" if /^\!\s+([^\r\n]+)/' | xargs -0 -r -I FILE svn remove 'FILE@'
```